# Powershell = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger Unable to pass value in variable

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I would like to edit scheduled task via PS but i can't pass the variable as argument to New-ScheduledTaskTrigger. I tried with "time = "02:40 AM"" and "$time = [datetime]"02:40 AM""

```
 $time = "02:40 AM"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "pc01" -ScriptBlock {$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName R

$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At $time
Set-ScheduledTask -Trigger $trigger -TaskName R
}
```

I receive following error: Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime".

Thank you for any help.

Comment: to pass a variable from your local machine via `Invoke-Command` try editing `$time` to `$using:time`

Answer (score 1):

Inside the scriptblock, the variable `$time` is unknown, so you muste either use the `using:` [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1#scope-modifiers) like this:

```
$time = [datetime]"02:40 AM"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "pc01" -ScriptBlock {
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At $using:time
    Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'R' | Set-ScheduledTask -Trigger $trigger
}
```

Or add a `param()` block inside the scriptblock and give the time via the `-ArgumentList` parameter

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "pc01" -ScriptBlock {
    param($time)
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At $time
    Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'R' | Set-ScheduledTask -Trigger $trigger
} -ArgumentList "02:40 AM"
```